# R: using apply family instead of for-loops for data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

First, some sample data:

```
location <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
mat <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1825),nrow=5,ncol=365))
t1<- c(258,265,306,355)
t2<- c(258,270,302,352)
t3<- c(258,275,310,353)
t4<- c(258,280,303,355)
t5<- c(258,285,312,356)
ts<-rbind(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5)
dat <-as.data.frame(cbind(location,mat,ts))
names(dat)[367:370] <- c("pl","vg","re","me")
```

`location` are the names of sites. `V1` to `V365` is the daily rainfall (with `V1` as 
the first day of the year). What I want to do is:

For each row (`location`), I want to produce three rainfall values based on the last 
four columns `pl`,`vg`, `re`,`me` (which specfies days of the year)

For example, for location `A`, the last four columns are:

`pl` = 258
`vg` = 265
`re` = 306
`me`= 355

Therefore, for location `A`, I want to produce three rainfall values which are sum of rainfall from:

`V258` to `V264`

`V265` to `V305` and

`V306` to `V355`

And do it for all the five locations.

What I did was:

```
 for(j in unique(dat$location)){

    loc <- dat[dat$location == j,]

    pl.val <- loc$pl + 1 # have to add + 1 since the rainfall starts from the second column
   vg.val <- loc$vg + 1
   re.val <- loc$re + 1
   me.val <- loc$me + 1

   rain1 <- sum(loc[,pl.val:vg.val]) 
   rain2 <- sum(loc[,(vg.val+ 1):re.val]) 
   rain3 <- sum(loc[,(re.val + 1):me.val]) 
}
```

I want to avoid using `for` loop and use the `apply` function instead. However, I am 
not familiar with how to use the apply function to do the calculation for all the rows
(location) in one go. Can anyone advise me how to go about it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

If I have one of those locations where rainfall values are NA and the other dates are NAs, how do I modify the code that is accepted as answer below. Here's the sample data

```
location <- c("A","B","C")
mat <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(365*3),nrow=3,ncol=365))
t1<- c(258,265,306,355)
t2<- c(258,NA,NA,NA)
t3<- c(258,275,310,353)
ts<-rbind(t1,t2,t3)
dat <-as.data.frame(cbind(location,mat,ts))
names(dat)[367:370] <- c("pl","vg","re","me")
dat[2,-c( 367:370)] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want speed.

I think the form of your data isn't good to calculate, because only col1 is character, col367:370 is different in kind, and very wide. Maybe it isn't good idea to calculate row by row. Basically R is good with calculating col by col.

If I were you, I would prepare the data like below form;

```
library(tidyverse)

dat1 <- dat[, -c(1, 367:370)] %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  set_names(location)

dat2 <- dat[, 367:370] %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  set_names(location)
```

And I recommend `map2()` to calculates each pair of cols. `.x` is each col of `dat1` and `.y` is each col of `dat2` (they are treated as vectors). Below code is fifty times as fast as yours.

```
map2(dat1, dat2, ~ {
  pl.val <- .y[1]
  vg.val <- .y[2]
  re.val <- .y[3]
  me.val <- .y[4]

  rain1 <- sum(.x[pl.val:vg.val]) 
  rain2 <- sum(.x[(vg.val+ 1):re.val]) 
  rain3 <- sum(.x[(re.val + 1):me.val]) 
  c(rain1 = rain1, rain2 = rain2, rain3 = rain3)
  }
)
```

**[additionnl (apply, mapply)]**

Note: It is difficult for `apply()` to treat `data.frame` having character and numeric because of transforming to matrix. So if you use `apply()`, it is needed to delete a location col.

```
apply(dat[,-1], MARGIN = 1, function(x){
  pl.val <- x[367 - 1]
  vg.val <- x[368 - 1]
  re.val <- x[369 - 1]
  me.val <- x[370 - 1]

  rain1 <- sum(x[pl.val:vg.val]) 
  rain2 <- sum(x[(vg.val+ 1):re.val]) 
  rain3 <- sum(x[(re.val + 1):me.val]) 
  c(rain1 = rain1, rain2 = rain2, rain3 = rain3)
})
```

`mapply()` is mostly the same as `map2()`. In this question, `mapply()` gives the best performance.

```
mapply(function(.x, .y){
  pl.val <- .y[1]
  vg.val <- .y[2]
  re.val <- .y[3]
  me.val <- .y[4]

  rain1 <- sum(.x[pl.val:vg.val]) 
  rain2 <- sum(.x[(vg.val+ 1):re.val]) 
  rain3 <- sum(.x[(re.val + 1):me.val]) 
  c(rain1 = rain1, rain2 = rain2, rain3 = rain3)
  }, dat1, dat2)
```

[benchmark]

```
Unit: microseconds
             expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval cld
 forloop_method() 14154.075 15074.555 17110.4060 16588.1200 18416.387 25869.836   100   c
    map2_method()   205.586   234.263   325.8762   313.9395   333.633  2072.911   100 a  
   apply_method()  1617.443  1684.812  1913.9187  1783.2480  1933.216  4189.687   100  b 
  mapply_method()   154.972   185.079   213.9370   210.2300   225.978   468.690   100 a
```

**[additional2 (error handling)]**

Below code is almost as fast as above code when there isn't NA. (Note: If it is in one line, you can omit `{}` of `if(...) { A } else { B }`, such as `if(...) A else B`.)

```
results <- map2(dat1, dat2, ~ {
  pl.val <- .y[1]
  vg.val <- .y[2]
  re.val <- .y[3]
  me.val <- .y[4]

  rain1 <- if(is.na(pl.val) | is.na(vg.val)) NA else sum(.x[pl.val:vg.val], na.rm = T)
  rain2 <- if(is.na(vg.val) | is.na(re.val)) NA else sum(.x[(vg.val+ 1):re.val], na.rm = T)
  rain3 <- if(is.na(re.val) | is.na(me.val)) NA else sum(.x[(re.val + 1):me.val], na.rm = T)
  c(rain1 = rain1, rain2 = rain2, rain3 = rain3)
  }
)

# If you want data.frame instead of list
invoke("rbind", results)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the faster solution.  A quick question: if a location does not have rainfall (for e.g. location "A" all rainfall values are NA), the code throws up an error. How do I sort it out. I could remove that location and run your function. But I would rather have NA in the final table for location A instead of removing A before doing the analysis. I have edited the sample data to reflect this.

Comment: @KS89; OK, I edited. If  you want `data.frame` instead of `list`, `invoke("rbind", results)` (or `invoke("cbind", results)`) gives it.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure how you wanted the returned rain days? Are they to be bound as 3 new columns?

Basically, here's the code... i'll walk through:
For each row in your `dat` data.frame, select the columns that represent the days, and then build a sequence of those numeric corresponding values, but step-down the next value so that we get the correct columns each time. Since we're now operating on each locations `slice` of the data, convert values to numeric, and sum the corresponding columns in our `apply` step. use `?sprintf` to append a `V` to each column number we get from our sequence creations, and return as a list. I then simply named the list vectors with the corresponding location's ID... if you wanted to append it to the data.frame it would be simple as well.

```
lapply(1:nrow(dat), function(i){
    d_idx <- dat[i,] %>% dplyr::select(dplyr::matches("pl|vg|re|me"))
    a_idx <- data.frame(
        s = as.numeric(d_idx[,1:3]), 
        e = c(as.numeric(d_idx[,2:3]) - 1, as.numeric(d_idx[[4]]))
    )
    as.list(apply(a_idx, 1, function(j){
        rowSums(dat[i, sprintf('V%s', seq(min(j),max(j)))])
    })) %>% setNames(sprintf('rain%s', 1:length(.)))
}) %>% setNames(dat$location)


$A
$A$rain1
[1] 2.391448

$A$rain2
[1] 21.58306

$A$rain3
[1] 27.805


$B
$B$rain1
[1] 5.339885

$B$rain2
[1] 16.57476

$B$rain3
[1] 26.37708


$C
$C$rain1
[1] 7.929777

$C$rain2
[1] 17.81324

$C$rain3
[1] 20.12217


$D
$D$rain1
[1] 9.715258

$D$rain2
[1] 11.2547

$D$rain3
[1] 25.93332


$E
$E$rain1
[1] 12.81343

$E$rain2
[1] 15.41595

$E$rain3
[1] 21.79217
```